# What's the difference between "There's no car." and "There are no cars."?

Tags: plural-forms

What's the difference between these two?

a. There's no car on the street.

b. There're no cars on the street.

or

a. There's no possible explanation for that.

b. There're no possible explanations for that.

Comment: What's the difference between one apple and two appleS? There IS one apple, there ARE two appleS!

Comment: I don't think you follow my question. Please read it again carefully.

Comment: Then enlighten me. What's the confusion?

Comment: @MaulikV — There **is** no **car** is obviously singular, there **are** no **cars** is obviously plural. But in **both** cases, there are _zero_ cars! So maybe the OP is confused as to how a sentence in the singular can mean the _same_ as a sentence in the plural. To answer _your_ question, there is _no_ difference between one apple an two apples, if you _do not have them_. The negation makes all the difference here.

Comment: @oerkelens - I think you should combine the comment you made to Maulik with your point about contractions you made to Frank. The meanings are essentially the same, the plural contraction is usually spelled as two words – I think those are the two most important points. The only thing left to address might be when a speaker might choose one over the other – if any tipping point even exists. To the O.P.: we could also add "There isn't any car on the street" and "There aren't any cars on the street" to the list of ways we could express this sentiment.

Answer (score 8):

Before I get to the sentences and their meaning, first a short note about *there're*.

It *is* used as a contraction, but not very commonly. It is perfectly fine to contract *are* to *'re*, but for pronunciation reasons this usually only happens after a vowel sound: *they're*, *you're*. The *r* sound at the end of *there* makes it more difficult to pronounce for most people, so most will prefer to use *there are*.

---

Now, for the sentences. There is an obvious difference between these two:

> There is no car.
>   There are no cars.

The first one is singular, the second one is plural. However, because there is a negation, the *result* is the same: there are *zero* cars. So as such, the two sentences both mean the same. They are also both grammatical.

Another way to say the same is using *any*, and the correct way of doing that (again singular and plural are correct!) would be:

> There is not any car.
>   There aren't any cars.

You could say *there are not any cars*, but the contraction feels more natural.

Now, if we have four ways to say the same thing, which one do we choose?

Actually, the difference between the four options is quiet small, but there is a little bit of difference in how we feel part of the message is stressed.

If we are talking about a single car, say a car that I have reserved at a car rental, but they messed up my reservation, you could have a conversation like this:

> `customer:` Where is my car?
>   `clerk   :` I'm sorry, I have no reservation for you. *There is no car* for you.
>   `customer:` well, if my reserved car isn't there, give me another one.
>   `clerk   :` I'm sorry, but *there isn't any car* available.
>   `customer:` You are a car rental company, and yet *there are no cars*?
>   `clerk   :` It has been very busy, and indeed, *there aren't any cars* left here.

Let's have a look at the messages behind the four phrases in this conversation:

*There is no car*: you expected a specific, singular car to be there, but it is not there.
*There isn't any car*: not only the specific car you wanted isn't there, there is no other single car for you.
*There are no cars*: I would expect there to be several cars, but that is not the case.
*There aren't any cars*: Really, no matter what kind of car you want, there are none!

Although there *is* a bit of a difference, most speakers would have no problem interchanging at least some of the options in the conversation. In general, adding *any* will add some stress to the absence.

Comment: What a neat dialogue between the clerk and the customer!

Comment: Just like "there aren't any cars" sounds better than "there are not any cars," I'd also say "there isn't any car" instead of "there is not any car". And frankly even that seems a bit off, though I can't say why.

Answer (score 1):

*there're* is contraction of *there are*. *

*In saying that it's worth noting that before a comment was made on this answer I would have regarded writing *there're* as 'wrong'. When I checked (via [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%27re&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cthere%20%27re%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BThere%20%27re%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20%27re%3B%2Cc0)) it seems that *there're* is used, although nothing like as often as *there are* - [see ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%27re%2C%20there%20are&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cthere%20%27re%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BThere%20%27re%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20%27re%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cthere%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthere%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThere%20are%3B%2Cc0). Note that early uses (roughly pre-1930's) of *there're* are not actually the word *there're*. In addition to that information I would also add, that as a native speaker, I would never, ever write *there're* unless it was in quoted speech as in  `"Run! There're hundreds of them" shouted Tom`. So my advice would be to always use *there are* until such times as *there're* becomes as well accepted as *there's* in writing. There are a number of questions/answers on ELU about *there're*. Here's one https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54752/using-therere-to-abbreviate-there-are?lq=1

.

*there's* is a contraction meaning either *there is* or *there has*.<sup>(1)</sup>

Both sentences, in each set, mean the same. The only difference is the second sentences use the plural.

*There is no car on the street* is probably not as familiar a phrase as *There are no cars on the street* because it's normal for there to be more than one car on any given street where cars are allowed.

If you are using *there's* to mean *there has* then the first sentences of both parts are ungrammatical.

---

<sup>(1)</sup>[There's](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/there-s?showCookiePolicy=true)  from Collins Dictionary at collinsdictionary.com

Comment: How does this answer the question? You're sure that _'re_ is not a common contraction of _are_? You should hear _some_ people, they're sure it is! But that contraction has little to nothing to do with the question...

Comment: @oerkelens You're absolutely right. _There're_ is used (I checked ngrams and it's quite common) I'd never seen it written before. Thanks.

Comment: @Frank - "quite common" is a relative term, and I don't know if I'd characterize _there're_ as [quite common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there+are%2C+there+is%2C+there's%2C+there're&year_start=1860&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). (It does get used, but not nearly so much as its [singular counterpart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there's%2Cthere're&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) – perhaps because it more difficult to enunciate.)

Comment: @J.R. I edited out the _common_ after oerkelens comment. I was surprised to find _there're_ is used at all. Contractions of _are_ are used but I'd never seen _there're_ written, except perhaps in direct speech. _There are_ is much more common but _there're_ appears often enough to say it is certainly in use and it's use is becoming [more common - ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%27re&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cthere%20%27re%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BThere%20%27re%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthere%20%27re%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Frank - We agree it's in use – there're plenty of examples we could find and cite – although it's also worth noting that my spell-checker put a red line under the one I just used. I realize that spell-checkers aren't always reliable; my point is that I'd probably consider this a "tween word" – acceptable in everyday conversation (if I could manage to utter it), but probably best avoided in a more formal document.

Comment: @J.R. I have no trouble saying it, in fact it probably is what I would say for 'there are' [theyrur - IPA from wikitionary /ˈðɛəɹˌəɹ/], but I wouldn't write it like that - ever.

Comment: @Frank - If you wouldn't write it – ever - then it's probably worth mentioning that in your answer. I think those asides are very helpful for learners. If someone read your answer here, without reading this conversation at the bottom, they could easily be led to believe that _there're_ is a normal, widely-used contraction. That's the only reason I brought this up. I'm not trying to nitpick, I'd just like to see the whole story told.

Comment: @J.R. Lots of OPs on ELL are learners that will use what we tell them in their homework/exams, they trust us. But we say/write lots of things that might sound acceptable in casual conversation or writing that do not respect usual received standards in teaching and might get an ELL learner getting a red pencil mark or a mark off their paper. "There are" is the perfect example. In an oral exam an EFL learner who says  /ðɛː(ɹ)/ will be appreciated for his command of spoken English, but if they write it, then it might get rejected as incorrect because [...]

Comment: [...] it isn't a received contraction in writing among some EFL teachers.

Comment: @J.R. updated to include my 'opinion' and also a link to one question (which links to others) on ELU.